# Does Agda have any support for renaming variables?

Tags: agda

By that I mean being able to do batch renaming in some local scope rather than having to do each place by hand. In my F# programming, I spent quite a lot of time doing it like that or using find/replace only to be amazed how great it is to have IDE support for renaming.

Agda is kind of a special case among languages as its variables can have special symbols that are difficult to type out, so that feature would be even more beneficial than is usual.

What is the prefered way to do renaming at the moment?

Comment: There is currently no special tooling for refactoring code in Agda.